# Unable to find a target named `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

Attempting to install pod in IOS for a React Native application.

I've added the target to my project.

This is the file structure of the project:
[image]

I am in the `ios` directory for the React Native project, and I'm running:

```
pod install
```

When I run pod install, I receive this error:

```
[!] Unable to find a target named `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` in project `PodApp.xcodeproj`, did find `PodApp` and `PodAppTests`.
```

This is what my `Podfile` looks like:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'PodApp' do

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'PodAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
  end

end
```

Comment: i have the same error, any help